# Flutter expand bottom navbar to show more options

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I wish to make a bottom navbar which initially shows 5 options, out of which last option is 'more' and when user taps on it, navbar expands vertically and then show couple of more options. So, exactly what happens is that initial navbar shifts upward, and similar kind of navbar comes below it to show rest of the options. Note: I am not talking about sub-category or sub-menu kind of thing, its just that initially last few options are hidden, and becomes visible when user tap on 'more'.

I also thought to use bottomsheet through kind of show/hide on click functionality, but saw that bottomsheet comes above navbar.

Here are the images for more clarity:
[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: You might have to implement your own nav bar for this use case.

Comment: Okay, any hint exactly how, at present I am using default BottomNavigationDrawer provided by flutter. Even if I use my custom navbar, I am not able to think how to achieve the functionality which I explained. That's the main hurdle for me.